# Bicycle disc brake rotors

Tags: brakes, shimano, hayes, rotor

It is time to change my bike's hydraulic disc brakes . Now I have a Hayes Stroker Ryde system , but I want to order a Shimano M395 instead . The question is that I don't know If I have to order the rotors with brakes or not . Both brakes are for 160 mm rotor but they don't look alike .

This is my hayes brake rotors

[image]

And this is the rotors of shimano m395[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as you existing rotors are in good condition and thicker than 1.6mm (minimum safe thickness) you should have no issue with using them with the Shimanos. There doesn't seem to be an industry standard specification for rotor thickness but it is generally taken to be between 1.8mm - 2.0mm. The new callipers will self adjust to the rotor width.

Clean your existing rotor up with some rubbing alcohol (or similar solvent which doesn't leave a residue) before installing the new brake system to ensure there's no contamination.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is the aluminum spiders on some rotors. ( i.e. Shimano ice-tech ) then can interfere with the install tabs on some brake pads ( i.e. Avid BB7 ). This is generally only an issue if the brake pads are installed from same side of the brake as the rotor.

Answer (score 1):

You would not need to change the rotors as they are both 160mm rotors but both are compatible if you want to change them.